# What can I do if I found an old uncashed check?

Tags: check

I was cleaning out a desk and found an old uncashed paycheck from 2013 ! Here's the thing, the check is for a little over $1600.00

Is there anything I can do to redeem this check?

Comment: You can sometimes request for the issuer of the check to give you new check. They don't always comply or make it easy but it is worth a shot. Otherwise it might have already been sent to your state's unclaimed property, check with them to see if it is there too.

Answer (score 6):

Since that check is ten years old, you shouldn't try and deposit or cash it. The bank would be expected to reject it.

In my experience after a few months to a year an employer will reach out and try to either get you to cash the check or send a replacement one. That should have happened back in 2013 or 2014. If you were still employed with them that would have been easy to do. If you were no longer employed with them they would have had to try and contact you at your last known address.

In the united states if they reached out a couple of times and you never responded they eventually would have turned the funds over to the state.  That is where you should start. If they were in one state and you lived in another check both states. Every US state has a website where you can see if you have any unclaimed funds. It is free to check, and free to get the money. There is no need to pay a 3rd party service.

It is possible that if you were still employed back in 2014, and had switched to direct deposit they already had sent you the funds directly to your bank account.

You can also contact the employer, but it is unlikely they can quickly determine what happened to your funds. It isn't like they keep proof of payment in the active records 10 years later.